# Media print.css in Chrome doesn't print html content

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a problem with the print.css in a website I'm working on.
Seems like only with chrome the print view doesn't work. When I see the print view, there are only the layout elements but without any text.

With Safari and Firefox, instead, it works fine.

My css files in the site are these:

```
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/960_16_col.css" media="screen and (min-width: 900px)" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" media="screen and (min-width: 900px)" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/tablet.css" media="screen and (max-width: 900px)" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/mobile.css" media="screen and (max-width: 480px)" />
    <link type="text/css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" href="css/print.css"/>
```

But if I remove the tablet and mobile css, even in Chrome I'm able to see the text content.

What could be the problem?

Very thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There's likely a definition inside the `css/table.css` or `css/mobile.css` that's "hiding" the content.

Search those files for:

- `display:none`
- `visibility:hidden`
- `text-indent:[someLargePostiveOrNegativeInteger]`

At some ["breakpoint"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries), the associated content is being "hidden" ...

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I found out that the problem was that I was using viewport instead of pixel to define the 'font-size'. Apparently they aren't shown in print mode. Thank you anyway!